# How to print a '\007' or '\a' (beep) in IDLE or Pydev

Tags: python

env:

- windows 7 English 32bit
- Python 2.7.3

I can print beep in IPython, but in Pydev or IDLE, it doesn't work.
It only print an unrecognized char but not make a beep sound.
Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't beep because it's up to the terminal to interpret `\a` for you, and IDLE and Pydev don't interpret it as an auditory beep.

If you just want to produce a beep, take a look at the [`winsound`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html) standard library module. If you want to get IDLE or Pydev to interpret BEL as a beep, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: winsound on win32 is my temporary substitute. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII BEL character only sounds a bell where a bell is supported. Many terminals and terminal emulators do give this special meaning to the BEL character, but as you noticed, IDLE and Pydev do not. It is not necessarily a bug, but merely a missing feature.

Comment: Why do them design to unsupport the beep sound?

Comment: @Honghe.Wu: They didn't design it to *not* support the BEL character; it's just that they didn't explictly *add* support for it. It's not something that just automatically works; code has to be added to support it.